# Split string into custom List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, split

I need to split a custom string into the following format using C#.

The following string: `AD=Demo,OU=WEB,OU=IT,L=MyCity,C=MyCountry`, i want to split it at comma into a

> List<CustomDictionary> myList = new
>   List<CustomDictionary>();

Based on the text above and after the split, the **myList** list should contain 5 objects of type CustomDictionary.

```
 object1.Key = AD
 object1.Value = Demo

 object2.Key = OU
 object2.Value = WEB

 object3.Key = OU
 object3.Value = IT

 object4.Key = L
 object4.Value = MyCity

 object5.Key = C
 object5.Value = MyCountry
```

Here is the CustomObject class

```
 public class CustomDictionary
 {
     public string Key { get; set; }
     public string Value { get; set; }

     public CustomDictionary(string key, string value)
     {
         this.Key = key;
         this.Value = value;
     }
 }
```

So far I tried this:

Here I am stuck!

```
  List<CustomDictionary> keyVal = new List<CustomDictionary>val.Split(',').Select(x=>x.Split('=')).Select(x=>x.));
```

where **val** is the actual string ...

Comment: Any reason you can't us the built in Active Directory classes?

Comment: Also, [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post your current code and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: @Oded the string is just a value I receive in the service call ...

Comment: I could have split this to a keyvalue pair (Dictionary), but I will have duplicate Key than, unless I will reverse the values but even than I am not sure I will ever receive non-duplicate values so I have to figure this out in some other way ...

Comment: So, what's wrong with a `List<KeyValuePair>`? It is not a dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With linq:

```
var query = from x in str.Split(',')
            let p = x.Split('=')
            select new CustomDictionary(p[0], p[1]);

var list = query.ToList();
```

Also seems like you want to get a dictionary as a result. If so, try this code:

```
var dict = str.Split(',').Select(x => x.Split('='))
                         .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

To handle duplicate keys, you can store objects in [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb460184.aspx). Just call `ToLookup` instead of `ToDictionaty`.

Comment: I made it at first with Dictionary but when I run the code, i got an exception because I have duplicate keys: OU ... so this was a lost. however it works fine with the first linq query you shown ...

Answer (score 2):

After splitting the second time you create a `CustomDictionary` from the items in that array, then use `ToList` to make a list of the result.

```
List<CustomDictionary> keyVal =
  val.Split(',')
  .Select(x => x.Split('='))
  .Select(a => new CustomDictionary(a[0], a[1]))
  .ToList();
```

There is already a class in the framework having a key and value, which you can use instead:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyVal =
  val.Split(',')
  .Select(x => x.Split('='))
  .Select(a => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(a[0], a[1]))
  .ToList();
```

You can also use a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of a list of key-value pairs. It stores the value based on the hash code of the key, so getting a value by key is much faster than looking through a list (but it doesn't retain the order of the items):

```
Dictionary<string, string> keyVal =
  val.Split(',')
  .Select(x => x.Split('='))
  .ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it:

```
var parts = theString.Split(',');

var myList = new List<CustomDictionary>();
foreach(string part in parts)
{
  var kvp = part.Split('=');
  myList.Add(new CustomDictionary(kvp[0], kvp[1]));
}
```

This can also be done using LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 2 `OU`s you can't use `Dictionary`. Instead  use `Lookup`

```
string input = "AD=Demo,OU=WEB,OU=IT,L=MyCity,C=MyCountry";

var dict = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\w+)=([^,$]+)").Cast<Match>()
            .ToLookup(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

what about `MyString.split(',');` and the on each string you get:

```
CO.key = SubString.split('=')[0];
CO.value = SubString.split('=')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ:

```
List<CustomDictionary> myList = (from x in input.Split(new char[] { ',' })
                                 select
                                 new CustomDictionary (x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf('=')), x.Substring(x.IndexOf('=') + 1))
                                ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "AD=Demo,OU=WEB,OU=IT,L=MyCity,C=MyCountry";

var result = str.Split(',').Select(s =>
{
    var tmp = s.Split('=');
    return new CustomDictionary(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
}).ToList();
```